# Best way to handle autoresizing of UIView with custom drawing

Tags: ios, objective-c, performance, core-graphics, drawrect

I'm working on a custom view, that has some specific Core Graphics drawings. I want to handle the view's autoresizing as efficiently as possible.

If I have a vertical line drawn in UIView, and the view's width stretches, the line's width will stretch with it. I want to keep the original width, therefore I redraw each time in `-layoutSubviews`:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    [super drawRect:rect];

    // ONLY drawing code ...
}

- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

This works fine, however I don't think this is a efficient approach - unless CGContext drawing is blazing fast.

So is it really fast? Or is there better way to handle view's autoresizing? (CALayer does not support autoresizing on iOS).

**UPDATE :**
this is going to be a reusable view. And its task is to draw visual representation of data, supplied by the dataSource. So in practice there could really be a lot of drawing. If it is impossible to get this any more optimized, then there's nothing I can do... but I seriously doubt I'm taking the right approach.

Comment: Have you actually tried it on a device to see if the drawing is actually not performant?

Comment: @LeoNatan this is going to be a reusable view. And its task is to draw visual representation of data, supplied by the dataSource. So in practice there could really be alot of drawing. If it is impossible to get this done any more optimized, then theres nothing i can do.. But, i seriously doubt i'm taking the right approach.

Comment: I added an answer with my thoughts.

Comment: I think this question is unanswerable without further information.

Comment: @vikingosegundo i updated the title, since the subject has evolved since i first asked the question

Comment: still there is no way to tell what technique would be better.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on what you mean by "fast" but in your case the answer is probably "No, CoreGraphics drawing isn't going to give you fantastic performance."

Whenever you draw in drawRect (even if you use CoreGraphics to do it) you're essentially drawing into a bitmap, which backs your view.  The bitmap is eventually sent over to the lower level graphics system, but it's a fundamentally slower process than (say) drawing into an OpenGL context.

When you have a view drawing with drawRect it's usually a good idea to imagine that every call to drawRect "creates" a bitmap, so you should minimize the number of times you need to call drawRect.

If all you want is a single vertical line, I would suggest making a simple view with a width of one point, configured to layout in the center of your root view and to stretch vertically.  You can color that view by giving it a background color, and it does not need to implement drawRect.

Comment: ..i mentioned vertical line as a example, to illustrate my concern. The actual drawing is somewhat complex. Perhaps you know of a better way to handle this, without recreating a bitmap each time bounds change? There must be a proper approach to this.

Comment: @user1244109 There's nothing wrong with using `drawRect` when you need to do complex custom drawing, and it's not *really* creating a new bitmap in each drawRect (though maybe a new bitmap will be created on the bounds change, but let's not speculate about UIView implementation details).  The real question is just how complex and custom your drawing is.  Is your drawing composed of "static" entities that merely change position?  If so maybe you can make separate views that draw those entities (using drawRect), but your root view could merely position those subviews.

Comment: thanks for your participation Aaron. please see update in the question

Answer (score 0):

Using views is usually not recommended, and drawing directly is actually preferred, especially when the scene is complex.

If you see your drawing code is taking a considerable toll, steps to optimize drawing further is to minimize drawing, by either only invalidating portions of the view rather than entirely (`setNeedsDisplayInRect:`) or using tiling to only draw portions.

For instance, when a view is resized, if you only need to draw in the areas where the view has changed, you can monitor and calculate the difference in size between current and previous layout, and only invalidate regions which have changed. **Edit:** It seems iOS does not allow partial view drawing, so you may need to move your drawing to a `CALayer`, and use that as the view's layer.

`CATiledLayer` can also give a possible solution, where you can cache and preload tiles and draw required tiles asynchronously and concurrently.

But before you take drastic measures, test your code in difficult conditions and see if your code is performant enough. Invalidating only updated regions can assist, but it is not always straightforward to limit drawing to a provided rectangle. Tiling adds even more difficulty, as the tiling mechanism requires learning, and elements are drawn on background threads, so concurrency issues also come in play.

Here is an interesting video on the subject of optimizing 2D drawing from Apple WWDC 2012:
https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/?include=506#506

Comment: «*Note that, because of the way that iPhone/iPod touch/iPad updates its screen, the entire view will be redrawn if you call -setNeedsDisplayInRect: or -setNeedsDisplay:.*» https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1708/_index.html

Comment: @vikingosegundo See [video of session 506 of WWDDC 2012](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/?include=506#506). Apple uses it to optimize drawing on an iPad app. I think that article is outdated.

Comment: @vikingosegundo Might be that they are drawing on a layer. I will update the answer.

Comment: I can't imagine how you'd justify "using views is usually not recommended" as general advice.  In a wide variety of circumstances a hierarchy of views (or layers, I guess, if you don't want need all the event handling) will be much more performant than a drawRect that produces the same results on screen.

Comment: @AaronGolden Not if the drawing is optimized. A view hierarchy (and to a smaller degree, a layer hierarchy) brings a lot of baggage that is not really needed, especially if a lot of data is to be drawn, as the edit to the question suggests.

Comment: but with many subviews / sublayers you can mark only some of them to layout/display. if done correctly this will increase performance.

Comment: @vikingosegundo Either the view manages its subviews, or you have to manage them all. Now, lets assume this is a view that will be used in a normal view hierarchy. Add subviews to it unrelated to the drawing code. Now it falls down to the developer to create an implementation that knows which views to layout and which not, and how. With sublayers this is easier, but not by much.

Comment: The developer knows the datasource, so he should know at anytime what view needs to be updated.

Comment: What if subviews are added externally, such as the system's layout guides?

Comment: I am talking about the views representing the datasource's data. if they are changed, only thous must be updated.